# Interpretation of residual plots -- constant variance of residuals

Tags: regression, anova, linear, minitab

[image: Output from minitab]

I am trying to analyze these residual plots.
Clearly, from the normal probability plot and histogram the standardized residuals are not normally distributed (it shows a moderate negative skew).

However, I am confused with the other two plots. I feel that the residuals vs fitted value is fairly constant, but I feel like there is a decreasing in variation (considering the spread near the fitted value of 53,000). The residual in order seems to be randomly distributed (am I right?).
Any clarifications would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The main thing to pick up from these plots is the set of four points with large negative residuals. All plots would seem well behaved otherwise. In a dataset this small you should able to go back and check them. Are the values trustworthy? Are there obvious reasons for those values being much lower than predicted? Do you need a different functional  form or another predictor? Is the order of observations arbitrary, in which case there is no point in trying to interpret the last plot, or does it represent a time order, in which case an autocorrelation check is needed?

Comment: The diagonal stripes on the top right plot presumably represent rounding in the original data (to the nearest thousand???).

Comment: You need a better title, possibly "Interpretation of residual plots". I removed "homosceda[sti]city" as this is just "constant variance" all over again.